how to reset streamlit data_editor "edited_rows" dict
I have the following code in streamlit:
        print(st.session_state[self._key]["edited_rows"])
        with grid_container:
            save_button_click = st.button(
                label="**Save**",
                key=f"{self._key}_save_button",
            ) if not is_read_only else False
            edited_df = st.data_editor(
                styled_data,
                hide_index=True,
                key=self._key,
                column_config=column_config
            )

        if save_button_click:
            self._save_editions(
                message_container,
                st.session_state[f"{self._key}_grid_state"]["pages"][
                    st.session_state[f"{self._key}_grid_state"]["current_page"] - 1
                ]
            )
            st.rerun()


    def _save_editions(self, message_container, page=None):
        if self._key not in st.session_state:
            return

        edited_rows = list(st.session_state[self._key]["edited_rows"].keys())
        edited_rows_indexes = (
            page.iloc[edited_rows].index
            if page is not None
            else edited_rows
        )

        if len(edited_rows_indexes) > 0:
            edited_rows = (
                self._controller.controller_data()["data"].iloc[edited_rows_indexes]
            )

            if len(edited_rows) > 0:
                edited_rows = self._update_dataframe(
                    edited_rows,
                    st.session_state[self._key]["edited_rows"]
                )

                response = self._controller.update(edited_rows)

                if response["type"] == "success":
                    message = "Changes saved automatically!!!"
                    st.session_state[self._key]["edited_rows"] = None
                else:
                    message = f"Not possible to save changes: `{response['text']}`"

                post_message(message_container, response["type"], message, timeout=5)

                if self._key == "pt_new_records_grid":
                    st.session_state["pt_new_records_data"] = pd.DataFrame()

I expect that after the st.rerun() the st.session_state[self._key]["edited_rows"].keys() would print None, but it prints the editions, which means that st.session_state[self._key]["edited_rows"] = None had no effect (I evaluate and the value is actually changed, but in the next run the change is lost and the value is the original one).
What am I doing wrong?
